# Number of elements in dynamic array of structures

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, realloc

I have these structures:

```
typedef struct g {
    int i;
    float f;
}Txy;

typedef struct s {
    Txy *x;
}Tstruct;
```

And I want x to be a dynamic array so I run this everytime I want to add a new element.

```
Tstruct s;

s.x = (Txy*)realloc(s.x, sizeof(Txy) );
```

After I add some elements to array I need to find out how many elements are in array in that moment.

```
int num = sizeof(s.x) / sizeof(s.x[0]);
```

I tried this but it does not work. What could be a problem?

Comment: `sizeof(s.x)` === size of the pointer.

Comment: Do you use funcionts ?

Comment: @SouravGhosh Hey, can you stop posting that topic on questions when it is not relevant at all, and merely distracts from the real problem?

Comment: @this With all due respect, do you know what is a _spam_?

Comment: @SouravGhosh Can you answer my question, or is the only answer you can provide (another) red herring?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with using `sizeof` on a pointer is that what you get is the size of the pointer and not what it points to.

If you need the size, you need to keep track of it yourself. Add a member field to the `Tstruct` structure for it, something like

```
typedef struct s {
    Txy *x;
    size_t size;  // size of x
}Tstruct;
```

It's up to you to decide if you want the size to be the number of elements or the size in bytes of the allocated memory.

Answer (score 1):

you forgot to indicate the new number of elements:

```
s.x = (Txy*)realloc(s.x, sizeof(Txy) * numElements);
```

Comment: If I want to add just one element isn't sizeof(Txy) enough? Or I have to add sizeof(Txy)*(current_number_of_elements + 1)

Comment: in that case it would be enough as numElements is 1..

Comment: I am still not sure about realloc. Its second argument 'size' means that size of the new memory block will be old_size + 'size' or the size of the new block will be just 'size'?